# Html css justify-content: space-between doesnt work correctly when parent is justify content center is active

Tags: html, css

I have the following laylout right now

[image: Sample image]

Now id really like to have all of the h2s with test next to each other with space between

I was told to add this to my css

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

[image: Example of desired result]

Id like to achieve a result similar to this however when I add

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

Nothing happens

here's the code I used

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #003959;
  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <h1>test</h1>
  <div style="justify-content: space-between;">
    <h2>test</h2>
    <h2>test</h2>
    <h2>test</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

I assume the issue is caused by the div parent but I'm very unsure how to solve this

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `display` to `flex` for `space-between` to work:

```css
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #003959;
  color: white;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <h1>test</h1>
  <div style="justify-content: space-between;display:flex;">
    <h2>test</h2>
    <h2>test</h2>
    <h2>test</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

If that spaces the test elements too far apart, try `center` instead of `space-between` and then add some left/right margins to them.

Comment: thank you for the help once stackoverflow allows me to ill accept your answer